# Rails 4 - create method depending on controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, controller

I have an application with multiple tables. For example Users and Posts.

I have created pages for the tables rendering the tables on the page. I have also created a layout for these pages.

At the bottom of the layout I have a create new button to add an entry to the table. I am trying to make the button change depending on the controller. For example the button link changes to 'new_user_path' when on the users page and 'new_post_path' when on the posts page.

I can't really find anything that explains how I can do this, if anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you could get controller and action name from `params`:

```
params[:controller], params[:action]
```

but instead checking controller name could be better use [contnet_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/content_for)

```
<% content_for :bottom_bar do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

and that in your layout

```
<%= yield :bottom_bar %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `current_page?`check in views to find what kind of action or controller that is.
Here are the docs to the function 
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/current_page%3F

Example could be like this:

```
<% if current_page?(controller: 'shop', action: 'checkout') then puts shop_checkout_path else shop_index_path end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/8-layouts-and-content-for) about using *content_for* in your layout.